# Accidently Pulled Down Branch with the Same Name

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, branching-and-merging

I accidentally pulled down a branch with the same name as a local branch

```
* 909a2b5 - (HEAD, feature/form) xxxx <imrane>
* c9d6bc5 - xxxx <imrane>
| * 6e96409 - (origin/feature) xxx <anandmv>
|/  
*   38e35d8 - (origin/develop, origin/HEAD, develop) xxx <imrane>
```

I had committed all changes to my local branch, then ran

```
git fetch origin
```

and then tried to track the remote branch and got the following error

```
git checkout --track origin/feature
error: there are still refs under 'refs/heads/feature'
fatal: Failed to lock ref for update: Is a directory
```

Questions:
1. How do I revert without losing the commits I had on feature/form
2. How do I pull down the branch without having a naming collision?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are slightly misinterpreting your situation:

- You do not need to revert anything, you didn’t lose anyting
- Your situation is as follows: You have a local branch named `feature/form`, the remote has branch a named `feature`. Now this may come as a surprise, but these names conflict. `feature/form` actually creates a *folder* named “feature” with a branch named “form" in it. Because of that you can not create a branch named “feature”, as a folder with that name already exists.
- `git checkout --track origin/feature` tries to create a branch named “feature”, which is not possible, so it fails.
- regarding question 2: Well, there just *is* a naming collision – these two branches can’t coexist in your local repo. But you **can** work on the remote `feature` branch without deleting or renaming your local `feature/form` branch – even though I would not really recommend that as it’s easy to get confused there.
- Running this command:

  ```
  git checkout -b mylocalname --track origin/feature
  ```

  will generate a local branch named `mylocalname` that tracks the remote branch `feature` on the remote `origin`.